# C++11でトライグラフを無効にしたい

Tags: c++, c++11

次のようなソースがあります。

test.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        puts("(???)");
        return 0;
}
```

これを `g++ test.cpp` の様にコンパイルすると、実行結果は期待通りです。
しかし `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp` とすると、`(???)`が`(?]`になってしまいます。

`clang++ -std=c++1z test.cpp` なら、期待通りに動作しますが、
Debian (jessie) の g++ 4.9.2 では `c++1z` を指定することができません。
Ubuntu (16.04) の g++ 5.4.0 では `c++1z` は指定でき、期待通りの動作です。

g++ 4.9.2 で c++11 を有効にして、かつトライグラフを無効にする方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: `-std=gnu++11` も興味深いのですが、できるだけ標準に準拠したいので、`CXXFLAGS` に `-Werror=trigraphs` を付けて、もしトライグラフが発動したときは、強制的にエラーにするようにし、`\?`でエスケープすることにしました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

トライグラフはC++言語仕様の一部であり、GCCのISO C++準拠モード(`-std=c++11`)ではトライグラフを無効化できないようです。

トライグラフを回避するには、(1)`\?`とエスケープするか、(2)文字列リテラルを分割する必要があります。また意図しないトライグラフ変換を避けるため、`-Wall`オプションの指定を強くおすすめします。

```
puts("(??\?)");   // (1)
puts("(??""?)");  // (2)

puts("(???)");  // "(?]"に変換される
// warning: trigraph ??) converted to ] [-Wtrigraphs]
```

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XuW4H0wnBDhHySkd

おまけ：次期標準C++1z(C++17予定)では[トライグラフが仕様から削除](http://faithandbrave.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/12/05/172553)されます。新しいGCCやClangへのc++1z準拠指定でトライグラフが無効化される理由はこれです。将来的には気にしなくても良くなるでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

`-std=c++11` の代わりに `-std=gnu++11` を使えば、トライグラフを無視してくれます。

g++ 独自の機能は使いたくない、純粋な標準に準拠したいということならば、`\`で`?`をエスケープするしかないと思います。

```
    puts("(\?\?\?)");
```